# C++ Converting string packet to iphdr - what should be the format of string packet?

Tags: c++, udp, hex, protocols, wireshark

So I have this line of code:

```
struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr*) packet.c_str();
```

from ip.h:

```
struct iphdr
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:4;
    unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error    "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
    u_int8_t tos;
    u_int16_t tot_len;
    u_int16_t id;
    u_int16_t frag_off;
    u_int8_t ttl;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t check;
    u_int32_t saddr;
    u_int32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
  };
```

I captured a DNS packet using wireshark and I got this sample packet:

```
0000   e0 8e 3c 1c c0 07 ac bc 32 83 84 d9 08 00 45 00
0010   00 3f 51 45 00 00 40 11 aa b3 c0 a8 fe 65 c0 a8
0020   fe fe 0e 76 00 35 00 2b d5 1c 9c 0a 01 00 00 01
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 03 77 77 77 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c
0040   65 03 63 6f 6d 02 70 68 00 00 01 00 01
```

I removed the eth header and so I'm left with this:

```
0000   45 00
0010   00 3f 51 45 00 00 40 11 aa b3 c0 a8 fe 65 c0 a8
0020   fe fe 0e 76 00 35 00 2b d5 1c 9c 0a 01 00 00 01
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 03 77 77 77 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c
0040   65 03 63 6f 6d 02 70 68 00 00 01 00 01
```

The first part (45 00 00 3f 51 45 00 00 40 11) translates to this:

```
45     0100 .... = Version: 4
       .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
00     Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
00 3f  Total Length: 63
51 45  Identification: 0x5145 (20805)
00 00  Flags: 0x00
       Fragment offset: 0
40     Time to live: 64
11     Protocol: UDP (17)
```

My question is: what should be the format of the string variable packet? I have tried this:

```
std::string packet = "45 00 00 3f 51 45 00 00 40 11";
```

but for ip_header->protocol I get **48 '0'** instead of 17.

Also I'm wondering, why is the protocol not on the 9th byte? I was assuming it should be on the 9th based on the structure of iphdr.

Would highly appreciate anyone's help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The packet should not contain *text*. What you're seeing in Wireshark is a hexadecimal representation of binary data. The data itself does not consist of those characters. (Much like the word "kitten" is not a kitten.)

Answer (score 1):

Your basic assumption has some problems. You're using a string and you assume that if you cast it to some structure definition it will automatically (and auto-magically) convert it to the proper binary representation of that structure definition. This is not the case. Let's say you have a structure `'struct Test { unsigned int t; }'` and a string `'std::string st = "12"'`. And you do `'struct Test *pt = st.c_str();'`. The ASCII representation of "12" would be 0x31 0x32 so now *pt points to a memory location starting with 31 32. Casting this to in integer (assume we have a big-endian system and assume the unsigned int is two bytes) results in 0x3132 (decimal 12594).